# Using TAGS with <script> on your websites

Tags: javascript, strings, html, dom

This function creates a series of links at a desired destination by the usage of a premade tag system.

**Usage:**

- `createMyTAGS_DATA` passes in a single line of all the links as: `LinkText;LinkAddress;;`
- `createMyTAGS_LOCATION` passes the destination to a `div`,`span`,... to render the result

**Result would be:**

> ```
> <a href="LindAddress1">LinkText1</a><a href="LindAddress2">LinkText2</a> [...]
> ```

**Note:** each of `tag(LinkText;LinkAddress;;)` must have more than 10 characters.

```html
<span onclick="createMyTAGS('LinkText1;LinkAddress1;;LinkText2;LinkAddress2;;','renderHERE');" style="cursor:pointer;"><b>click here</b></span>

<div id="renderHERE"></div>

<script>
    function createMyTAGS(createMyTAGS_DATA,createMyTAGS_LOCATION){
    try{ var linkTags = createMyTAGS_DATA;
         var v1 = createMyTAGS_LOCATION;
    while (linkTags !== '' && linkTags.indexOf(";;") > 10){
    var linkNew = linkTags.slice(0, linkTags.indexOf(";;"));
    var linkText = linkNew.slice(0, linkNew.indexOf(";"));
    linkTags = linkTags.replace(linkNew+';;', '');
    linkNew = linkNew.replace(linkText+';', '');
    linkNew = '<a href="'+linkNew+'" title="'+linkNew+'" target="_blank">'+
              linkText+'</a> ';
    document.getElementById(v1).innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById(v1).innerHTML + linkNew;
    }
    }catch(err){alert('createMyTAGS: '+err.message+
    '; - statement('+createMyTAGS_DATA+','+createMyTAGS_LOCATION+')')}
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

From a once over;

- Indent your code, it will be easier to read
- Use lowerCamelCase for your names `createMyTAGS` -> `createMyTags`, though personally I would call the function `createLinks`

  - I would call `createMyTAGS_DATA` simply `s` for string or `data`
  - I would call `createMyTAGS_LOCATION` either `id` or `element` or `elementID`, you wont then feel the need to assign that parameter to the slightly better named `linkTags`
- For your string handling, you should read up on `.split()`, it would make this so much easier
- `alert` statements are terrible, this function should never go wrong. Consider using `console.log` instead if you must.
- If you have long variables or chained variables (which you should avoid), consider `+=`:
  `document.getElementById(v1).innerHTML = document.getElementById(v1).innerHTML + linkNew;`
  becomes
  `document.getElementById(v1).innerHTML += linkNew;`
- Consider using `addEventListener` instead of assigning the event listener straight into the HTML

My counter proposal:

```js
function createLinks(data, elementId){
      
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId),
        links = data.split(';;'),
        html = element.innerHTML,
        linkParts, url, text;
  
    links.forEach( function( link ){
        linkParts = link.split(';');
        text = linkParts[0];
        url = linkParts[1];
        html += '<a href="'+url+'" title="'+text+'" target="_blank">'+text+'</a> ';   
    });

    element.innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<span onclick="createLinks('LinkText1;LinkAddress1;;LinkText2;LinkAddress2;;','renderHERE');" style="cursor:pointer;"><b>click here</b></span>

<div id="renderHERE"></div>
```

Comment: from a once again. the original production of my participation with fully functional code, has nothing to do with this that i didn't did. make sure to exclude myself so to make it yours. the TAG is the key functionally of the code and has nothing to o with anchors. unbelievable